# Required doesn't work after adding test Yup

Tags: reactjs, yup

This is what i've done

```
subject: Yup.string().test('checkForManualText', 'Please, add hand-written subject as well',
            function(inputValue) {
                let newMessage = inputValue.replace(/\{{(.+?)\}}/gmi, '').replace('/\s/gmi', '').trim()
                return newMessage.length !== 0
            }).required()
```

Now the `test` validation works fine, but the `required` stopped working. Before adding test, all was good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `required` when using `.test`. Returning `false` will show the error message. Just add null/undefined check to the string.

```
subject: Yup.string().test('checkForManualText', 'Please, add hand-written subject as well',
            function(inputValue) {
                if(!inputValue) return false;
                let newMessage = inputValue.replace(/\{{(.+?)\}}/gmi, '').replace('/\s/gmi', '').trim()
                return newMessage.length !== 0
            })
```

[Working Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-mui-v5-forked-fob3bb?file=/src/App.js)